# GitHub API v4 Graphql: Get current authorized user organizations and their repositories

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, octokit-js

In GitHub API v3 with **repo** and **user** authorization scopes, I can get my organizations with `GET /user/orgs` (https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user, with Octokit REST JS, `octokit.orgs.listForAuthenticatedUser()`) and for each organization, to get the repositories which I have access, `GET /orgs/:org/repos` (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories, with Octokit, `octokit.repos.listForOrg({ org: orgs.data[i].login })`).

However, with the same authentication scope (user and repos), running this Graphql query

```
query getOrgsRepos {
  viewer {
    organizations(first: 10) {
      nodes {
        repositories(first: 10) {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "organizations": {
        "nodes": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Graphql Explorer result (https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/), but running on my JS authed (**user** and **repo** scopes) app returns the same empty result*

How to have the same behaviour with API v4, **without having to give further permissions**?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this very issue today. Unfortunately, as of the timestamp indicated at the bottom of this answer, GitHub's GraphQL API is not on par with its REST API. The following query would only yield the viewer's **public orgs** i.e. what an unauthenticated session would show listed on their github.com profile under "Organizations".

```
query getOrgs {
  viewer {
    organizations(first: 100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And there is no equivalent of `octokit.orgs.listForAuthenticatedUser()` in their GraphQL schema which basically fetches the REST endpoint, [`/user/orgs`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user), to list organizations for the authenticated user. From [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user):

> /user/orgs only lists organizations that your authorization allows you
> to operate on in some way (e.g., you can list teams with read:org
> scope, you can publicize your organization membership with user scope,
> etc.). Therefore, this API requires at least user or read:org scope.
> OAuth requests with insufficient scope receive a 403 Forbidden
> response.

In other words, with a personal access token with sufficient scopes, `/user/orgs` returns the same list shown on [Your Organizations](https://github.com/settings/organizations) page. If you're authenticated using an OAuth access token, then the list is pretty much the same as shown under "Organization Access" on the user's [Authorized OAuth Apps](https://github.com/settings/applications) page for your OAuth app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query had a problem with missing the organization `login`:

```
query getOrgsRepos {
  viewer {
    organizations(first: 10) {
      nodes {
        login
        repositories(first: 10) {
          nodes {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get responses with only those scopes.